# Can I differentiate $x$ with respect to $|x|$?

Tags: derivatives

First, I naively thought that it would be like this.
$$\frac{dx}{d|x|} = \frac{1}{\frac{d|x|}{dx}}$$

Then, however, I had an apprehension that since $|x|$ is not differentiable on $x=0$, this conclusion might be mathematically wrong.

So... can I differentiate $x$ with respect to $|x|$ like this, or do I need some other conditions (such as "$0$ is not included in $x$'s domain" or whatever)?

Comment: $x$ is not a function of $|x|$, so you would have to define what you mean by $dx/d|x|$ for the inequality to make sense.

Comment: What function is $x$ of $|x|$? Note that restricting to (connected) domains where $|x|$ is invertible makes the problem trivial since either $|x| = x$ or $|x| = -x$ on such a domain.